# How To Create Generic JSON Parsing Code?

Tags: json, parsing, elixir

So I'm parsing a list returned by parsing some json with [jsx](https://github.com/talentdeficit/jsx).  I'm pulling out some selected values by searching for a tuple with a particular name, like so:

```
defp get_link([{"link",_link} | _t]), do: _link
defp get_link([_h | _t]), do: get_link(_t)
defp get_link([]), do: ""
```

I'm doing this same thing for several separate elements that I want to extract and when I see lots of code that only varies on one parameter, I smell a bad code smell.  I mean code like this:

```
defp get_link([{"link",_link} | _t]), do: _link
defp get_link([_h | _t]), do: get_link(_t)
defp get_link([]), do: ""

defp get_last_updated([{"last updated",_last_updated | _t]), do: _last_updated
defp get_last_updated([_h | _t]), do: get_last_updated(_t)
defp get_last_updated([]), do: ""

defp get_creator([{"creator",_creator} | _t]), do: _creator
defp get_creator([_h | _t]), do: get_creator(_t)
defp get_creator([]), do: ""
```

smells of violation of the DRY principle to me.

So I thought I might do something like this:

```
defp get_json_element([{element_to_get,value_of_element} | _t]), do: _value_of_element
defp get_json_element([_h | _t]), do: get_json_element(_t)
defp get_json_element([]), do: ""
```

But assuming that would work (it compiles but I'm not sure that it would do what I want), how do I call it?  I can't call `get_json_element(["link", _link])` (or at least I don't think I can)  I mean normally I'd pass the list returned by jsx.decode to the various get_X functions but then how do I pass the pattern match expression?  I'm sorry--I don't think I've phrased my question very well but I can't figure out how to phrase it better.

Is this one of those cases where I should use a macro to reduce the repetitious code?  If so, has anyone already written a macro of this sort?

Also wondering if there's a better way to indicate an empty string.  Using "" just doesn't seem the best approach to me.  Or is there another value that I could return?  Maybe return nil?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could definitely use a macro

You could use https://github.com/Licenser/jsxd library to manipulate data structures returned by jsx

You could use a generic function like

```
def get(json, key, default \\ nil) do                                                                            
  case List.keyfind(json, key, 0, default) do
    {^key, value} -> value
    ^default -> default
  end 
end
```

Your solution

```
defp get_json_element([{element_to_get,value_of_element} | _t]), do: _value_of_element
defp get_json_element([_h | _t]), do: get_json_element(_t)
defp get_json_element([]), do: ""
```

Would not work because `{element_to_get, value_of_element}` would match any tuple with the same shape `{_, _}`